# Dahua api give 401 Unauthorised error in get method angular js

Tags: angularjs, video-streaming, nodes

I call a dahua API for preset response in angular js but it gives me a **401 Unauthorised error**.
My code is below :

```
var streamurl='http://admin:123456@192.168.1.202/cgi-bin/ptz.cgi?action=start&channel=0&code=PositionABS&arg1=180&arg2=190&arg3=10';

$http.get(streamurl, { withCredentials: true })
    .then(function(response2) {
        console.log(response2.data);
});
```

Comment: You first check- what is expected URL is required for this. Probably you are missing correct format. check header also.

Answer (score 0):

> **How to Fix the 401 Unauthorized Error**
>
> 1. Check for errors in the URL. It's possible that the 401 Unauthorized error appeared because the URL was typed incorrectly or the link that was clicked on points to the wrong URL - one that is for authorized users only.
> 2. If you're sure the URL is valid, visit the website's main page and look for a link that says Login or Secure Access. Enter your credentials here and then try the page again. If you don't have credentials, follow the instructions provided on the website for setting up an account.
> 3. If you're sure the page you're trying to reach shouldn't need authorization, the 401 Unauthorized error message may be a mistake. At that point, it's probably best to contact the webmaster or other website contact and inform them of the problem.
> 4. The 401 Unauthorized error can also appear immediately after login, which is an indication that the website received your username and password but found something about them to be invalid (e.g. your password is incorrect). Follow whatever process is in place at the website to regain access to their system.

From https://www.lifewire.com/401-unauthorized-error-what-it-is-and-how-to-fix-it-2622934

Answer (score 0):

I could be wrong but I think you are getting login screen with that request. I've read through documentation and I have found your way of authentication only working on `rtsp://` protocol, and for http I believe you should modify headers, and encode your username/pasword to base64, here's documentation:

ftp://ftp.wintel.fi/drivers/dahua/SDK-HTTP_ohjelmointi/DAHUA_IPC_HTTP_API_V1.00x.pdf

Also you should probably use this since you are using AngularJS/NodeJS, it will make your life easier - or check how this guy did his authentication and "borrow" from him:

https://github.com/nayrnet/node-dahua-api